# android : create a full transparent view

Tags: android, transparency, background-color

I have an activity with a gradient background. Inside this activity there is a linerar layout containing three text views. This layout's background color is black. I want see the activity's gradient background through the textviews. But if I set textview background to transparent then it will be black color, which is linear layout's background color. how can I make textviews to see activity's gradient color?

[image]

Comment: I think you'll have to create a custom view that'd clip it's parent.